# Database data into textbox

Tags: c#, database, textbox

Is there a way to display data from the database into the textbox but every time you click NEXT new row displays. I have this code but it doesn't work like I want it to because it displays all data into a textbox and not one row at a time.

```
private void buttonNEXT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("data source = people.sqlite");
    conn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
    com.CommandText = "SELECT id, name, surname FROM people;";
    SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        textBox1.Text += reader["id"].ToString(); 
        textBox2.Text += reader["name"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text += reader["surname"].ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: WinForms? You probably want BindingNavigator. But you could use a Reader if you want forward only access - just exec your reader outside of the click event and store it in a variable then call Read once each button click, not "while(reader.Read())"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `Next` and `Previous` button and don't want to use a `BindingNavigator` control on your form, you can use a `DataSet` to store data and an `SQLiteDataAdapter` to fill it.
So you can have a function to fill and return a data set:

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string ConnectionString, string SQL)
{
    SQLiteConnectionconn = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter ();
    SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = SQL;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

Then you should keep its returns value to a `global variable` in your main function like `FormLoad` :

```
dataset ds; // global variable
int index = 0; // for loop over dataset
private void frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = GetDataSet("data source = people.sqlite","SELECT id, name, surname FROM people;");
}
```

And in your button click:

```
private void buttonNEXT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.Text = ds.Tables["People"].Rows[i]["id"].ToString(); 
     textBox2.Text = ds.Tables["People"].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
     textBox3.Text = ds.Tables["People"].Rows[i]["surname"].ToString();
     i++;
}
```

**Note:** You should check for `i` variable value by each click, it should not be bigger than ds.Tables["People"].Rows.Count

Do the same for previous button if you want it also.

Comment: You still have half the problem because of "+="